# KoGrid: Default sorting not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kogrid

As part of **[koGrid](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid) 2.1.1** I was not able to make the default sorting to work, meaning that if you want your grid to be sorted by a specific column/direction you won't get the expected behavior. Default sorting in koGrid is achieved by sortInfo while configuring the gridOptions for the very first time.

I have created an example using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alansouzati/UEEbJ/) which demonstrates this issue. You can notice that the list is not sorted by name, even that I've specified the **sortInfo** to do so.

**1. Initializing koGrid with sort info:**

```
        this.gridOptions = {
            data: self.myData,
            ...
            sortInfo: ko.observable({
                column: { "field": "name" },
                "direction": "asc" 
            })
            ...
        };
```

**2. Notice the list is not sorted, neither the arrow is showing up:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed koGrid 2.2.1 debug js to use the sortInfo, if specified. Basically, I made two changes as follows:

**1. Created a function which returns column by field into the Grid object:**

```
window.kg.Grid = function (options) {
...
self.columnByField = function (field) {
        if(field) {
           var column;
           $.each(self.columns(), function (i, c) {
              if(field == c.field) {
                 column = c;
                 return false;
              }
           });
           return column;
        }
    }
...
}
```

**2. Changed Grid object init method to look for sortInfo and sort the column:**

```
window.kg.Grid = function (options) {
...
self.init = function () {
  ...
   self.buildColumns();
   var sortingProperties = self.sortInfo.peek();
   if(sortingProperties) {
      var col = self.columnByField(sortingProperties.column.field);
      if(col) {
         col.sortDirection(sortingProperties.direction === ASC ? DESC : ASC);
         col.sort();
      }

   }
  ...
}
...
}
```

By doing this the default sorting problem is solved. I have created a fork [project on GitHub](https://raw.github.com/alansouzati/KoGrid) and added the new debug js file there.

Now when you load the grid for the very first time the sorting works as the below image shows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add function for gridOption sortInfo like below

```
 ....
    sortInfo: this.sortDetails;
  }
```

Define function sortDetails like below

```
this.sortDetails.subscribe(function (data) {
        this.sortData.sort(function (left, right) {
            return left == right ? 0 : (left < right ? -1 : 1);
        });
    });
```